# Can a PDF have a user password and no owner password?

Tags: pdf

As a PDF document can be open by either a user or owner password, can I protect the opening of the PDF by setting a user password, without setting an owner password (leaving all the permissions open)?

I am using a library that sets the default `owner_password` to an empty string. If I set the `user_password` to a non-empty string, I need to set the `owner_password` as well, otherwise the document will be opened without a prompt. So I set:

```
owner_password = user_password
```

I read the [specification](https://www.adobe.com/content/dam/acom/en/devnet/pdf/pdfs/pdf_reference_archives/PDFReference.pdf) (page 74) but I could not find the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the underlying algorithms, the specification says

> If there is no owner password, use the user password instead.

*(ISO 32000-1, section 7.6.3.4 Password Algorithms)*

Thus, *without setting an owner password* is the same as *using the same password for user and owner*, just like you did yourself.

Concerning *"(leaving all the permissions open)"*, though: encrypted documents are partially treated differently from unencrypted ones, even if all permissions are given.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:**

If you desire to **not** have any permission restrictions, then the answer is *yes*.

Comment: Thanks Joseph. What if I dont want to restrict any permission? As far as I understood, “Opening the doc” is not among the “User access permissions” in the specs.

Comment: @Victor, I updated my answer, for some reason I had the impression you wanted to restrict permissions.